# Effects of a constant magnetic field on the human body (especially blood circulation and ion channels)?

Tags: human-biology, mri

Recently, while searching for the safety of MRI, I read in several places that hemoglobin and iron in the blood are not significantly affected by magnetic fields, so MRI is safe.  However, since the human body contains many kinds of metal ions, I'm wondering what effect would the long-term exposure to magnetic fields have on the human body, unlike in the case of MRI.

Comment: You might be interested to see the video of a frog levitating due to the strong (inhomogeneous) magnetic field. This experiment earned its authors the Ig-Nobel prize... just a few years before they received the real Nobel for discovering a way to obtain single layers of graphene: https://slate.com/business/2014/05/nobel-prize-in-physics-andre-geim-went-from-levitating-frogs-to-sciences-highest-honor.html